# Connecting two domain controllers in Active Directory Server 2012

Tags: virtualbox, domain, active-directory, windows-server-2012, replication

I want to setup virtual test environment at home using Windows Server 2012 R2. What I've done so far:

1. Installed two virtual boxes of win server 2012.
2. Promoted both to Domain Controllers, installed AD DS, DNS.
3. I've assigned static IP address to both, Computers can see each other on the network, they can see each other in server manager, I've also added them both to the server Pool.

Now to the problem. How can I make so that the replication of AD DS works? Basically when I create any object in AD I want it to be replicated on the other DC. Currently even tho they are in the same domain the replication does not work. I have been browsing the web for some time now, and TechNet is to complex for my current knowledge level.

Comment: You're looking for multi master, it sounds like you added the second dc as a client

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to find out the cause of the issue.

Problem was caused by the fact I created two domain controllers as stand alone ones so I think they were able to communicate on network level, but the all the replication stuff was not properly implemented.
To be precise - while installing the second DC during AD DS role installation, I should have chosen the option to "ADD SERVER TO EXISTING DOMAIN" (which allowed me to chose the replication "schema"(not sure if this is the correct word) instead of "CREATE NOT DOMAIN IN NEW FOREST".

The problem is entirely solved and I can now replicate the objects.

I have followed this specific guide while setting up another box with Win Server 2012.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20098.setting-up-additional-active-directory-domain-controller-with-windows-server-2012.aspx

PS. Thanks for the answer I now know what can I use the repadmin tool, which propably will come handy soon.

Answer (score 1):

First off, some basic advice in your situation to ensure replication is able to happen properly:

1. Confirm each DC can ping the other's IP address
2. Confirm each DC can ping the other using the fully qualified hostname (e.g. `dc2.contoso.internal`).  If you cannot, check to make sure each DC's Local Area Connection adapter's DNS Server is configured to point to the *other* DC's IP address.

You use the `repadmin` command to check replication between Domain Controllers in an Active Directory domain.  From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736355%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

1. Open a Command Prompt.
2. Type the following command, and then press ENTER:

   `repadmin /showrepl servername /u: domainname \ username /pw:*`
3. When you are prompted for a password, type the password for the user account that you provided, and then press ENTER.

If you find that there are problems with replication between your DCs, refer to the Technet article [Troubleshooting Active Directory Replication Problems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738415%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for help.  There's quite a but involved but hopefully with a simple setup like yours it won't be too hard to solve.